# How to bake materials [With complex node setup] into Texture in blender 2.9?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, texture-baking

I want to convert my snow material into texture and I followed the baking method but for some reason only the sides of the object are baked any kind of help or fix will be appreciated

[image]

my node setup for material is as follows

[image]

The required material render is as follows I need the glittery snow effect to the snow material but only the top face of the object wont render on the texture

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ Consider uploading a blend file so we can better diagnose your problem

Comment: @NascentSpace thanks for the suggestion please feel free to download the blend file and let me know the issue I may be facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edges of your snow object are very large n-gons:

[image]

The vertices of the n-gons do seem to be coplanar, and the normals appear to be facing the right direction, so I’m not entirely sure why this causes any trouble. But empirically, they do seem to be the source of the issue—if I remove them, the problem goes away:

[image]

---

If you need the edge faces, an easy way to recreate them is to select the outermost edge loop, then extrude downwards along the Z axis:

[image]

To make the lowermost vertices coplanar, you can then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd> to scale to zero along the Z axis:

[image]

Now you can re-unwrap the mesh, and for baking, I recommend using <kbd>UV ▸ Lightmap Pack</kbd>, since that will fill the space as optimally as possible. Then re-bake:

[image]

(Note that I’ve used a small sample size here for a short baking time, which is why the result looks so noisy, but obviously you should bake at your normal resolution to get better results.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution it may be because i used bool tool to fix the displace mod i will surely try doing your solution and see if it works awesome :)

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you so much :) @Alexis King